# SSH - still offering the wrong ssh key

Tags: github, ssh

`ssh` is still offering up the wrong ssh key to the ssh server.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa  git@my-new-host -v
```

and in `.ssh/config`

```
Host my-new-host
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa
User git
```

The output from `ssh -T` is:

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa  git@my-new-host -v
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for my-new-host
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:91
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.113]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi abraxor! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3252, received 1776 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12550.5, received 6854.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Anything to do with `debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory`?

If it helps both `/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa` and `/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa.pub` exist.

and with extra debugging:

```
ssh -T git@my-new-host -i ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa -vvv
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for my-new-host
debug1: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config line 23: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:91
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:91
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.30.253.112
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:91
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7faca240dac0), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa (0x7faca26012c0), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa (0x7faca240d310), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:tiBoG7eFalMe2h9TvaqSIFWhMzwCldzENxN3fwdUQ+Q
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:tiBoG7eFalMe2h9TvaqSIFWhMzwCldzENxN3fwdUQ+Q
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.112]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env AUTOJUMP_ERROR_PATH
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_path
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env AUTOJUMP_SOURCED
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env IRBRC
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env MY_RUBY_HOME
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env _system_type
debug3: Ignored env rvm_path
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env rvm_prefix
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env _system_arch
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env _system_version
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env FIGNORE
debug3: Ignored env rvm_version
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env GEM_PATH
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env RUBY_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env _system_name
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 89
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 9/(89)
Hi <wrong user>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 89 to efd 9
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Transferred: sent 3252, received 1776 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4064.8, received 2219.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

==== UPDATE 1

My `~/.ssh/config` contains

Host *
        IdentitiesOnly yes

==== UPDATE 2

If I run `cd ~/.ssh` and `rm id_rsa*` then it offers up the correct ssh key.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`? If so, can you copy your config to `~/.ssh/config2`, remove everything except the necessary lines you already mentioned above and and try `ssh -F ~/.ssh/config2 ...`?

Comment: I have `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` at the top on a line by its own. Then `Host my-new-host
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa
User git
`. Seems like this bare line at the top is overriding everything else perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. `IdentityFile` is a list of options. All the matches are aggregated into a list and then tried in order. See [ssh_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), where it says: **It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence**. What's confusing is that up front it says that command line takes precedence, which obviously is not the case...

Comment: Yes, the command line doesn't seem to have any effect. I wonder if running ssh-agent also confuses priorities somehow. Getting rid of `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` from the top of the file and deleting identities from `ssh-agent` seemed to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh` by default offers the keys that are in the default locations. If you want to alter this behavior, you need to use `IdentitiesOnly yes` option in your `ssh_config`.

Comment: I did have that - see the UPDATE.

Comment: What all contains your configuration files?